# Angular ng-repeat filter: ¿How to specify filter fields?

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

Ok, looks easy, but not.

I want to perform a simply angular filter, but i need to specify which fields of my array use in filter.

A Basic filter is:

```
 <li ng-repeat="person in app.people | filter: app.search">
```

A One-Field filter is:

```
<li ng-repeat="person in app.people | filter: {Surname: app.search}">
```

How can i specify more than one field for filter?
Something like:

```
<li ng-repeat="person in app.people | filter: {Name,Surname: app.search}">
```

Here a Plunker with Basic Filter and One-Field filter: https://jsfiddle.net/odLz1v71/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, I would suggest you add a filter function in your controller like this:

```
vm.searchFilter = function(item){
    // Add your own search logic here
    return item.Name.includes(vm.search) || item.Surname.includes(vm.search);
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="person in app.people | filter: app.searchFilter">
```

Comment: Ok, I can't believe Angular not have this behaviour natively... I'm going to use this filter function, but i'm going to add "toLowerCase()" to both properties and to search value. Tks a lot.

Comment: The Angular team can't predict, nor include, every use case for filtering - that'd introduce a lot of bloat and confuse new users of a framework with an already steep learning curve.

Comment: Adding `toLowerCase()` is a good idea. That's the kind of thing I meant by the "// Add your own search logic here"-comment. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with the basic filter directly, but you can provide a function for the `filter` filter to use that will do this check for you:

```
  vm.checkName = function (value) {
    return value.Name.indexOf(vm.search) > -1 || value.Surname.indexOf(vm.search) > -1;
  };
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/odLz1v71/4/